# PHP insert problems

Tags: php, mysql

Righ,t so on my website an admin puts the information into a form and then this is sent and becomes a news feed on the main page (Title, Body, Dateposted), but for some reason, (And I've checked against working code) this code is not working and I don't know why, can someone help me?

```
<?php
        $post = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(`title`,`body`,`date_posted`) VALUES('$title','$body','$date')");

        mysql_close($connect);

        header("Location: news.php");
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "The body of the news post you entered is too short.";
    }
} 
?>
```

my datebase rows:

```
[id]
[title]
[body]
[date_posted]
```

Comment: Your code is a mess and incomplete, this way we can't make any heads or tails of it. Probably your 'body'-variable contains quotes (single quotes) so the query is invalid - try to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for example.

Comment: What specifically is the problem? If that is your whole script then the database connection isn't open, not sure if that's your error or not.

Comment: I guess you’re having a syntax error due to the data in `$title`, `$body`, or `$date`. See [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for more information.

Comment: Could do with getting the exact error you get.

Comment: Add `echo mysql_error()` after the query to see the error message.

Comment: That's the shortend version of my script, because the escape checker on here meant I couldn't show the rest of my code, but the variables are not inserting into the database, I have already acquired a connection and used mysql_real_escape_string, I'm not sure why my entry is not inserting into the database though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the query as such. Unless you post the error message from `mysql_error()` (and comment out the redirect so that you see the message) there's not much anyone can do to help. It's also good practice to run queries as `mysql_query( ... ) or die( mysql_error() )` so that you'll always see the query errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work if your ID field is designated as being AUTO-INCREMENTING

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

**EDIT**

The other technique you could adopt is to put your sql into a variable and when you hit problems you can echo it out onto the page (or into your error_log).  It just means doing this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO news(`title`,`body`,`date_posted`) VALUES('$title','$body','$date')";
$post = mysql_query($sql);
// now have an optional line of debug
echo $sql;
```

Comment: When in doubt if PHP or your sql is to blame substitute some real data.. ie INSERT INTO news(`title`,`body`,`date_posted`) VALUES('test','test','test')"

Comment: Thankyou, I never though or error testing in this form with an INSERT statement.